# Can a partition be larger than 4G byte?

Tags: backup, partitions, mediatek

**Is there a limitation for a partition to be up to 4G byte?**

I have a strange case in which in cat /proc/partition the userdata is idenntified as 5.5G, while trying to backup and restore that partition with mediatek's "sp flash" tool keep failing.

It seems that sp flash tool use smaller size than real partition size, i.e. in the scatter text file I see size of 0x60000000 (1.6G):

```
partition_index: SYS23
partition_name: userdata
file_name: userdata.img
is_download: true
type: EXT4_IMG
linear_start_addr: 0x84000000
physical_start_addr: 0x84000000
partition_size: 0x60000000
region: EMMC_USER
storage: HW_STORAGE_EMMC
boundary_check: true
is_reserved: false
operation_type: UPDATE
empty_boot_needed: false
reserve: 0x00
```

I tried to change in text from 0x60000000 to 0x14CF80000 , use the readback to backup and then restore, but still got failure in boot (data corrupted screen)

I use meditek device MT6737M with "sp flash tool".

There is something basic I don't understand here:

1. I think the chip is 64-bit chip, so it should not be limited to 4G.
2. Maybe the limitation is in sp flash tool ?
3. So, how is it that manufacture initial data partition works without any issues. It is size of 0x1A86250 (smaller than 1.6G and also smaller than 5.5G).

Another interesting thing; doing backup and restore with twrp works well (yet I think it uses other format ex4.win, which seems to be compressed format).

Is it possible maybe to backup and restore all ROM with "sp flash" tool without using additional tools (like droid) ? Maybe that will work better than backup of a specific parition.

Thank for any idea,

ranran

Comment: What do you call G?

Comment: I mean 4Gbyte , I'll edit the question

Comment: The question you ask at the beginning of you post is far different than the one you ask at the end... The first question is simple, this would depend on the partition table type and specific filesystem, with a GPT partition table and ext4 file systems, there is no limit you would see in a mobile device. Your other question is outside my realm of expertise (this should really be 2 distinctly different question)